# sbt package java.io.FileNotFoundException (Permission denied)

Tags: macos, playframework, sbt

I have a strange issue running sbt package on a Play 2.2.1 project. It worked fine on my old Mac (same Mac OS version, 10.11.4) but I cannot find out how to get it to work on the new one. Clean repo cloned from Bitbucket, Play 2.2.1 installed locally, I tried both with Homebrew - using homebrew/versions because brew replaced play with activator - and play package from playframework.com. The error I get while I try to package is the following:

```
[error] (compile:packageBin) java.io.FileNotFoundException: /Users/my_user/my_project/target/scala-2.10/classes/MyClass.class (Permission denied)
```

The project is compiling and running correctly, including corresponding MyClass.scala.

I tried to chown project folder and Play folder, and to `chmod 777 -R project folder`, without any luck.

On any other computer (including a Win VM hosted on my Mac through VMWare), doing these simple steps is enough:

1. git clone repo
2. play war.

So I think it's something related to my Mac, but I'm not able to find what's wrong.

Any idea?

Comment: Did you check that the file actually has the new permission? Perhaps change it explicitly and try again.

Comment: I investigated a little more, it seems that the file is not created with the compilation performed by `sbt package`. If I run `sbt compile` I find the class file at the expected path. If I try `sbt package` it crashes as I mentioned before. If I run `sbt compile` again after trying to package, it compiles only 1 Scala source, exactly the one which is missed by `sbt package`. Is there any difference between sbt standalone compilation and sbt package compilation?

Comment: Yes. `sbt package` or `sbt dist` will create a new directory and a compressed file.

Comment: Yes, I mean: it seems that when I run `sbt package` it performs also a compilation. In this kind of compilation that specific class file is not generated. The problem occurs before creating the new directory and the new compressed file.